# Elasticsearch range query for string

Tags: elasticsearch

The ES index contains a "PRICE" field mapped as a string (due to various reasons): e.g. "2.00" or "245.00"

Running a RANGE FROM/TO (e.g. "5" to "20") query also shows documents with prices such as "500.00", "1515.00" etc.

Does anyone have a functional solution how to circumvent these additional out of range documents from showing up?

Comment: The range in your case is a string comparison, while you need floating point comparison. Is there a way you could change the field type? Number stored as string wont help much. Alternatively, you could add another field that holds the actual boolean value?

Comment: I am trying to avoid changing the field type. But if there is no other way, then yes, it probably can be implemented.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps adding another field of floating point is an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new field like "PRICE_VAL" (or using multi_field "PRICE.val") and explicit map it to "float" or "double" type.

After that, index both the string value and the number value of "PRICE". Now you can do a range query on "PRICE_VAL" without touching the "PRICE" field.